# Задача на создание функции JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Написать функцию, которая принимает три параметра n1,
n2 и n3 где число n1 – стартовое число массива, n2 -
количество элементов массива, n3 – количество массивов.
Функция возвращает двумерный массив, в котором первый
массив начинается с n1 и содержит в себе n2 элементов, а
каждый последующий массив начинается с n1+1.

Помогите пожалуйста написать на чистом js

Answer (score 2):

```
function getArray(n1, n2, n3) {
            var a = [];
            var start = n1;
            for (var i = 1; i <= n3; i++) {
                var j;
                var innerA = [];
                for (j = start; j < start + n2; j++) {
                    innerA.push(j);
                }
                start = ++n1;
                a.push(innerA);
            }
            return a;
        }
```

Comment: последующие массивы создаются как продолжение того массива. а они должны начинатся с n1+1

Comment: нужно присвоить переменной start = ++n1. Исправлено